# Calculate Average for Amount for certain date range in a year based on month

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I have a table like below :

| ID | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-03 |
| 1 | 200 | 2022-01-04 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-05 |
| 1 | 340 | 2022-01-06 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-26 |
| 1 | 567 | 2022-01-27 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-28 |
| 1 | 598 | 2022-01-31 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-02-01 |
| 1 | 787 | 2022-02-02 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-02-03 |
| 1 | 5340 | 2022-02-04 |

PROBLEM :-

So I have to calculate average of column where StartDate = 03/01/2022 (3rd Jan 2022) and for each month it would be like for January Average of Amount from StartDate to 25th Jan, then for Feb Startdate to 22nd Feb, so this date logic is also there

```
SET @Last = (SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @Date) 
                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -6 
                    When 'Saturday' THEN -5
                    ELSE -7 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Date)))

RETURN @Last
```

| ID | Amount | Date | Last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 340 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 567 | 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 40 | 2022-01-28 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-01-31 | 2022-01-25 |
| 1 | 589 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-22 |
| 1 | 540 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-02-22 |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-02-03 | 2022-02-22 |
| 1 | 5340 | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-22 |

Like the above table..
Now if I calculate Avg(Amount), from 3rd jan to 25th Jan for Jan and 3rd Jan to 22nd Feb and so on.. It's not giving correct average, like it is calculating the rest of the days amount also. Also grouping by is grouping month wise not as where clause

```
Select Avg(Amount) from Table
where Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND Last
```

StartDate is fixed @ 3rd Jan.
This is not giving the correct Avg. Any other way I could get the required data?

Comment: it's not giving `2407/5 = 481.4` ? for 3rd Jan

Comment: No, Though got the answer, have to create a temp table with date range for each month and join it to get the average for that date range